# Multiple aggregations in a single SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with roughly the following structure:

```
id | datetime | value
---------------------
```

What I would like is get a results with the following structure:

```
id | value_avg_overall | value_avg_last_month | value_avg_last_week
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I am using `JOIN`, that is constructing a query similar to that one:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT_OVERALL INNER JOIN SELECT_LAST_MONTH ON SELECT_OVERALL.id = SELECT_LAST_MONTH.id
    )
INNER JOIN SELECT_LAST_WEEK ON SELECT_LAST_WEEK.id = SELECT_LAST_MONTH.id;
```

I have simplified the query to make it more readable, that `SELECT_*` statements are simple `SELECT` statements using `GROUP BY` together with `AVG()` for respective time ranges.

Is this the most effective way to perform multiple aggregations and return all of them in a single result set in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  id, 
  avg(value) as value_avg_overall,
  avg(case when datetime > date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month) then value end)
    as value_avg_last_month,
  avg(case when datetime > date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 week) then value end)
    as value_avg_last_week
from mytable
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it without joins.

```
SELECT id, AVG(value), AVG(IF(date BETWEEN x AND y, value, NULL)) FROM table GROUP BY id
```